# Overhead of D classes

Tags: class, d, overhead

I thought I heard that D classes have two words (2 void*) of overhead instead of the one word required by C++. I also heard that the vtable layout is incompatible with C++. Do I remember correctly? If so what is the rationale for these decisions?

Comment: There is no need for it to be "heard" - the source is there, go take a look for yourself. :)

Comment: If that's your thing, cloning git repos and spending hours puzzling over 100,000+ of lines of source code hoping to find the answer to a simple question, sure. As for me I'll just ask if someone already knows the answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things:

1. In C++, a class that has no virtual functions will have *zero* overhead.
2. In D, a class always inherits virtual functions from `Object`, so it always has that `__vptr` overhead, but also has a `__monitor`, which C++ class objects don't have.
3. In both C++ and D, there will be additional `vptr` for each interface that the class implements.

The vtable layout is incompatible with C++ because D includes a pointer to a `TypeInfo` instance, which has runtime type information about the class. C++ obviously doesn't have that, so it is incompatible.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can use extern(C++) to build a compatible vtable. Probably also should be said that structs in D can be used when no overhead is desired.

Comment: Well, I sure hope the D devs change this implementation. Why would non-synchronized classes have a "__monitor"? Also, while C++ classes wouldn't have this TypeInfo thingie, that doesn't have to prevent C++ from calling D virtual functions and vice versa: just put the TypeInfo at vptr[-1] where it doesn't get in the way. There has been talk of eliminating opCmp, opEqual, etc. from Object; hopefully they would consider adding C++ binary compatibility around the same time, at least for simple cases. (Yeah, there's extern(C++), but what's the downside of compatibility-by-default?)

Comment: Basically, if you're spamming objects in sufficient number that four bytes make a difference, something about your design is broken. D has struct for POD types. Also: isn't C++ itself sufficient lesson in downsides of backwards compatibility?

Comment: Have to agree with @FeepingCreature, if those 4 or 8 bytes are really making a difference then you are probably creating too many class instances to start with. Take advantage of bulk efficiency and combine many instances into one.

Answer (score 4):

The extra pointer is to a monitor object for synchronized classes (there have apparently been talks about removing it for unsynchronized classes but that hasn't happened).  The layout is documented in the [ABI section](http://dlang.org/abi.html) of the spec.

I'm not sure how the vtable layout differs from how C++ compilers do it. Someone else can probably answer that.

Comment: Just to clarify, though, you can get zero-overhead objects w/o virtual functions in D by using structs and using `alias this` to simulate inheritance.